# Passing objects in Javascript/knockout js function losing values

Tags: javascript, sorting, knockout.js, widget

So I'm trying to pass an object into a function but every time I do it seemingly loses the values of the properties I'm trying to access. There's a little bit of knockout js too.

```
onload: function() {
   widget.thing = ko.observable();
   var viewModel = new objectThing(arg1, arg2, arg3);
   widget.sort(viewModel);
   widget.thing(viewModel);
}
```

That's the onload function I was trying to send the viewModel to a function to sort it (view model has an array in it with the things I need to sort)

```
sort: function(viewModel) {
   console.log(viewModel) //which actually console logs it with all the values inside it
   console.log(viewModel.someProperty) //it'll somehow be undefined (basically lost its value)
}
```

Any idea as to why this is happening? Or am I passing it in wrong? I've been trying to figure this out for weeks now

EDIT: The someProperty wasn't set int the arguments because originally when it starts the new object, it send other things to set it up. The someProperty is that array I had mentioned

Comment: We cannot really say, as there isn't enough code here. Is there any asynchronicity? You never *set* the `someProperty` as far as I can see, so perhaps it's populated at a later point in time. Or perhaps there is some other code that runs and sets/unsets that property. It's possible you're passing around different objects at different times and you set the property on one but try to sort the other.

Comment: @VLAZ The someProperty wasn't set int the arguments because originally when it starts the new object, it send other things to set it up. The someProperty is that array I had mentioned. It's a work thing